# Bollinger band entry opening price is incorrect

Tags: mql4

Building a strategy for practice based on Bollinger bands and stochastics.

What should happen is that if the `Close` of a 5 minute bar is above the upper band and the stochastic has gone above 80, a `sell` order should enter, and conversely lower band 20.

However, when I run it to test in `MT4`, I notice that the trades are wildly off the entry mark ( opening inside the Bollinger bands and not outside, for example ). Rather than opening at the `Close` of a bar, they are several pips too high or too low.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
extern int    MagicNumber  =  1;
extern double Lots         =  1;
extern double StopLoss     =  5;
extern double TakeProfit   = 15;
extern int    TrailingStop =  0;
       int    ThisBarTrade =  0;

int start() {
   double MyPoint = Point;
   if ( Digits == 3 || Digits == 5 ) MyPoint = Point * 10;

   double TheStopLoss   = 0;
   double TheTakeProfit = 0;

   if ( TotalOrdersCount() == 0 ) {
        if ( Bars != ThisBarTrade ) {
            ThisBarTrade = Bars;
            int result   = 0;
            if (  Open[0] <  iBands( NULL, 0, 20, 2, 0, PRICE_CLOSE, MODE_LOWER, 0 )
               && 20      >  iStochastic( NULL, 0, 12, 1, 3, MODE_SMA, 1, MODE_MAIN, 0 )
               && 0       == OrdersTotal()
               ) // Here is your open [Buy] rule -------------------
            {
               result = OrderSend( Symbol(), OP_BUY, Lots, Ask, 0, 0, 0, "", MagicNumber, 0, Blue );
               if ( result > 0 )
               {
                  TheStopLoss   = 0;
                  TheTakeProfit = 0;
                  if ( TakeProfit > 0 ) TheTakeProfit = Ask + MyPoint * TakeProfit;
                  if ( StopLoss   > 0 ) TheStopLoss   = Ask - MyPoint * StopLoss;
                  OrderSelect( result, SELECT_BY_TICKET );
                  OrderModify( OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble( TheStopLoss, Digits ), NormalizeDouble( TheTakeProfit, Digits ), 0, Green );
               }
               return( 0 ); // JIT/RET --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> 
            }

            if (  Open[0] >  iBands( NULL, 0,  20, 2, 0, PRICE_CLOSE,  MODE_UPPER, 0 )
               && 80      <  iStochastic( NULL, 0, 12, 1, 3, MODE_SMA, 1, MODE_MAIN, 0 )
               && 0       == OrdersTotal()
               ) // Here is your open [Sell] rule -----------------------
            {
               result = OrderSend( Symbol(), OP_SELL, Lots, Bid, 0, 0, 0, "", MagicNumber, 0, Red );
               if ( result > 0 )
               {
                  TheStopLoss   = 0;
                  TheTakeProfit = 0;
                  if ( TakeProfit > 0 ) TheTakeProfit = Bid - MyPoint * TakeProfit;
                  if ( StopLoss   > 0 ) TheStopLoss   = Bid + MyPoint * StopLoss;
                  OrderSelect( result, SELECT_BY_TICKET );
                  OrderModify( OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), NormalizeDouble( TheStopLoss, Digits ), NormalizeDouble( TheTakeProfit, Digits ), 0, Green );
               }
               return( 0 ); // JIT/RET --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> 
            }
         }
         for ( int cnt = 0; cnt < OrdersTotal(); cnt++ ) {
            OrderSelect( cnt, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES );
            if (  OrderType()        <= OP_SELL     // !PENDING ORDER
               && OrderSymbol()      == Symbol()    // !ANOTHER MARKET
               && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber // !ANOTHER EA/MMI TRADE
               )
            {
               if ( OrderType() == OP_BUY )
               {
                  if ( TrailingStop > 0 )
                  {
                     if ( Bid - OrderOpenPrice() > MyPoint * TrailingStop )
                     {
                        if ( OrderStopLoss() < Bid - MyPoint * TrailingStop )
                        {
                           OrderModify( OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), Bid - TrailingStop * MyPoint, OrderTakeProfit(), 0, Green );
                           return( 0 ); // JIT/RET --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> 
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
               else 
               {
                  if ( TrailingStop > 0 )
                  {                 
                     if ( OrderOpenPrice() - Ask > MyPoint * TrailingStop )
                     {
                        if (  OrderStopLoss() > ( Ask + MyPoint * TrailingStop )
                           || OrderStopLoss() == 0 
                           )
                        {
                           OrderModify( OrderTicket(), OrderOpenPrice(), Ask + MyPoint * TrailingStop, OrderTakeProfit(), 0, Red );
                           return( 0 ); // JIT/RET --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> --> 
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
      return( 0 );
}

int TotalOrdersCount()
{
  int result = 0;
  for ( int i = 0; i < OrdersTotal(); i++ )
  {
     OrderSelect( i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES );
     if ( OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber ) result++;
  }
  return( result );
}
```

Comment: David, in case your backtesting is being run for some remarkable amount of time ( fully-meshed optimisation scenarios et al ), your focus shall be also directed to a code-execution efficiecy. Your conditions do spend valuable time on re-execution of operations, that shall be avoided. A better code-execution may save you hours in your deep-backtesting time-budget. **Another issue** to be rather repaired is an MT4 server-side sensitivity to non-normalised prices in OrderSend() / OrderModify() execution ( that you will not see in back-testing, but ... having that in Live/Production **kills...** )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your use of the `iBand()` and `iStochastic()`, you are using **SHIFT 0** (the last param). Which means you are extracting the value of the **CURRENT** (market-edge) candle.  However, as the current candle have not ended yet, its value keep changing base on the new incoming price. That is why your trades are entered at seemingly random price-points.

What you may want is to refer to the PREVIOUS (ended) candle, which means the SHIFT should be 1 instead of 0.